# How to make navigation bar of pure css slider?

Tags: css, slider

[image]I want to make navigation bar of CSS slider that I have made.

[Here](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/CSS3-Cycle-Image-Slider/) is the live demo you can see.

And i also want to slide images to horizontally,

any idea how i can achieve this?

There was also a error show when i post my complete code, so here is i added complete coding of css in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsn0/4z9qY/) don't worry the images wont show but it has complete coding.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="content-slider">
       <div id="slider">
          <div id="mask">
             <ul>
            <li id="first" class="firstanimation">
                   <a href="#">
                      <img src="images/img_1.jpg" alt="Cougar"/>
                   </a>
                   <div class="tooltip">
                      <h1>Cougar</h1>
                   </div>
                </li>

                <li id="second" class="secondanimation">
                   <a href="#">
                      <img src="images/img_2.jpg" alt="Lions"/>
                   </a>
                   <div class="tooltip">
                       <h1>Lions</h1>
                   </div>
                </li>

                <li id="third" class="thirdanimation">
                   <a href="#">
                      <img src="images/img_3.jpg" alt="Snowalker"/>
                   </a>
                   <div class="tooltip">
                      <h1>Snowalker</h1>
                   </div>
                </li>

                <li id="fourth" class="fourthanimation">
                   <a href="#">
                      <img src="images/img_4.jpg" alt="Howling"/>
                   </a>
                   <div class="tooltip">
                      <h1>Howling</h1>
                   </div>
                </li>

                <li id="fifth" class="fifthanimation">
                   <a href="#">
                      <img src="images/img_5.jpg" alt="Sunbathing"/>
                   </a>
                   <div class="tooltip">
                      <h1>Sunbathing</h1>
                   </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <div class="progress-bar"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
   background: #eaeaea url(../img/bg.png) repeat;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: "Open Sans", serif;
   min-width: 960px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   color: #aaa;
}

.content h1 {
   font-size: 48px;
   color: #000;
   text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #f4f4f4;
   text-align: center;
   padding:60px 0 30px; 
}

/* LAYOUT */
.container {
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 960px;
}

/* CONTENT SLIDER */
#content-slider {
   width: 100%;
   height: 360px;
   margin: 10px auto 0;
}
/* SLIDER */
#slider {
   background: #000;
   border: 5px solid #eaeaea;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   height: 320px;
   width: 680px;
   margin: 40px auto 0;
   overflow: visible;
   position: relative;
}
#mask {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 320px;
}
#slider ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position: relative;
}
#slider li {
   width: 680px;
   height: 320px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -325px;
   list-style: none;
} 

#slider li.firstanimation {
   -moz-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;   
   -webkit-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;        
}
#slider li.secondanimation {
   -moz-animation: cycletwo 25s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: cycletwo 25s linear infinite;     
}
#slider li.thirdanimation {
   -moz-animation: cyclethree 25s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: cyclethree 25s linear infinite;       
}
#slider li.fourthanimation {
   -moz-animation: cyclefour 25s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: cyclefour 25s linear infinite;        
}
#slider li.fifthanimation {
   -moz-animation: cyclefive 25s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: cyclefive 25s linear infinite;        
}

#slider .tooltip {
   background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.7 );
   width: 300px;
   height: 60px;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 75px;
   left: -320px;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}
#slider .tooltip h1 {
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weight: 300;
   line-height: 60px;
   padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
#slider li#first:hover .tooltip, 
#slider li#second:hover .tooltip, 
#slider li#third:hover .tooltip, 
#slider li#fourth:hover .tooltip, 
#slider li#fifth:hover .tooltip {
   left: 0px;
}
#slider:hover li, 
#slider:hover .progress-bar {
   -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

/* PROGRESS BAR */
.progress-bar { 
   position: relative;
   top: -5px;
   width: 680px; 
   height: 5px;
   background: #000;
   -moz-animation: fullexpand 25s ease-out infinite;
   -webkit-animation: fullexpand 25s ease-out infinite;
}
```

Comment: Can you add more description to what type of navigation you're aiming for? Perhaps a picture and an attempt at the navigation itself? And do you want it to always transition horizontally or just some of the time?

Comment: Yes i added the pic you can now see the nav of that slider,and sure transitions also as you can see in the jsfiddle where i put a demo of slider.

Comment: I see no reason to do such stuff in pure CSS. It's overly verbose, hardly maintainable and all the other bad words you can imagine. Something you want to do in 300 lines of CSS needs less than 20 lines of JS - jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scroll horizontally you simply change the `top` values in the animations and `#slider li` to `left`s (I copy it over to Word and use the replace function there), [**Demo of that**](http://jsfiddle.net/4z9qY/1/). If you want them to scroll the other way, you can change the `left`s to `right`s, [**Demo of that**](http://jsfiddle.net/4z9qY/2/)

The look you are going for uses "radio" buttons. I don't know if it's *impossible* to do what you want with pure CSS, but it would take some crazy manipulations of the animation

With javascript it is easier, but the CSS animations still make it difficult. After a while of thinking I came up with [**this solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/4z9qY/4/) (buggy version, look below for better one) that relies on the class names for the animations.

After a good bit more work, I was able to come up with a solution that included a transition to the next picture, [**which can be found here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4z9qY/7/)! It's quite a piece of work now, but I hope the comments make it easier to understand. I'm not so sure you can do it in pure CSS anymore, haha.

The javascript I wrote could probably be shortened some, I didn't spend too much time making it  more efficient. The only error I saw is a brief black space on the first radio click and if you click too fast sometimes there is no transition. I hope it suits your needs!

Here is the added code for the final version found just above:

```
/* Javascript */
// Obtain the objects within javascript to use
var slider = document.getElementById('slider'),
    one   = document.getElementsByClassName('firstanimation')[0],
    two   = document.getElementsByClassName('secondanimation')[0],
    three = document.getElementsByClassName('thirdanimation')[0],
    four  = document.getElementsByClassName('fourthanimation')[0],
    five  = document.getElementsByClassName('fifthanimation')[0],
    // Hidden element that a 5s animation is applied to
    hidden = document.getElementById('hidden'),
    // Create an array of the li elements to make manipulating easier
    liArray = [one, two, three, four, five],
    // Obtain the radio buttons
    radios = document.getElementsByName('picture'),
    // For optimization and easy access later on
    liNum = liArray.length,
    // The bar at the bottom
    progress = document.getElementById('progress-bar'),
    // The li currently showing
    currNum,
    // Prefixes for the PrefixedEvent function
    pfx = ["webkit", "moz", "MS", "o", ""];

// Give each radio button an onclick function
for(var i = 0; i < liNum; i++) {
    // The following line is necessary to prevent them all from being 5
    radios[i].i = i;
    radios[i].onclick = function() { changePic(this.i) };  
}

// Changes the radio every time a slide animates to the left
PrefixedEvent(hidden, 'AnimationIteration', function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < liNum; i++) {
        // Checks to see which is checked
        if(radios[i].checked) {
            // Uncheckds the checked one
            radios[i].checked = false;
            // Checks the next one (first if there is no next one)
            if(i + 1 < liNum) {
                radios[i + 1].checked = true;
            } else {
                radios[0].checked = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
});

// Makes using animationiteration easier cross-browser
function PrefixedEvent(element, type, callback) {
    for (var p = 0; p < pfx.length; p++) {
        if (!pfx[p]) type = type.toLowerCase();
        element.addEventListener(pfx[p]+type, callback, false);
    }
}

// Transitions from one slide to the clicked one, sets new animation order based on choice
function changePic(nextNum) {
    // Gets the li being displayed currently
    for(var j = 0; j < liNum; j ++) {
        var computedStyle =  window.getComputedStyle(liArray[j]),
            rightPos = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('right');
        if(rightPos == "0px") {
            currNum = j;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Removes the animations for all the slider elements
    one.className = '';
    two.className = '';
    three.className = '';
    four.className = '';
    five.className = '';
    hidden.className = '';
    progress.className = '';  

    // Checks to see if it's a different element
    if(nextNum != currNum)
    {
        // If it is, animate the new one in from the right, slide current to left
        liArray[nextNum].style.right = "-685px";        
        liArray[currNum].style.right = "0px";        

        liArray[nextNum].style.right = "0px";
        liArray[currNum].style.right = "685px";        
    } else {
        // If it's not, leave it
        liArray[currNum].style.right = "0px";
    }

    // Necessary to initialize another animation (known CSS flaw)
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Resets animation order based on the clicked radio
        if(nextNum == 0) {
            one.className = 'firstanimation';
            two.className = 'secondanimation';
            three.className = 'thirdanimation';
            four.className = 'fourthanimation';
            five.className = 'fifthanimation';     
            hidden.className = 'timer';
            progress.className = 'progress';
        }
        if(nextNum == 1) {  
            one.className = 'fifthanimation';  
            two.className = 'firstanimation';
            three.className = 'secondanimation';
            four.className = 'thirdanimation';
            five.className = 'fourthanimation';     
            hidden.className = 'timer';
            progress.className = 'progress';
        }
        if(nextNum == 2) {  
            one.className = 'fourthanimation';
            two.className = 'fifthanimation';  
            three.className = 'firstanimation';
            four.className = 'secondanimation';
            five.className = 'thirdanimation';     
            hidden.className = 'timer';
            progress.className = 'progress';
        }
        if(nextNum == 3) {  
            one.className = 'thirdanimation';
            two.className = 'fourthanimation';
            three.className = 'fifthanimation';  
            four.className = 'firstanimation';
            five.className = 'secondanimation';   
            hidden.className = 'timer';
            progress.className = 'progress';
        }
        if(nextNum == 4) {  
            one.className = 'secondanimation';
            two.className = 'thirdanimation';
            three.className = 'fourthanimation';
            four.className = 'fifthanimation';  
            five.className = 'firstanimation';     
            hidden.className = 'timer';
            progress.className = 'progress';
        }        

        // Moves the previous image to the right with the rest
        liArray[currNum].style.right = "-685px";

    }, 500 /* Transition length in milliseconds */);
}

/* Added HTML */
<!-- Under #slider and #mask... -->
<li id="hidden" class='timer'></li>

<!-- Under #content-slider... -->
<nav id='photoNav'>
    <input type="radio" name="picture" checked="true" id="navOne" />
    <input type="radio" name="picture" id="navTwo" />
    <input type="radio" name="picture" id="navThree" />
    <input type="radio" name="picture" id="navFour" />
    <input type="radio" name="picture" id="navFive" />
</nav>

/* Added CSS */
#hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events:none;    
}
#hidden.timer {
    -mos-animation: nothing 5s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: nothing 5s linear infinite;
    animation: nothing 5s linear infinite;
}
#photoNav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left:480px;    
    margin-left: -60px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#photoNav input {
    cursor:pointer;
}
#progress-bar { 
    position:relative;
    top:-5px;
    width:680px; 
    height:5px;
    background:#000;
}
#progress-bar.progress {
    -moz-animation:fullexpand 25s ease-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation:fullexpand 25s ease-out infinite;
    animation:fullexpand 25s ease-out infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes nothing { 0% {} 100%  {} }
@-webkit-keyframes nothing { 0% {} 100%  {} }
@keyframes nothing { 0% {} 100%  {} }

/* And some other smaller things not worth the space */
```

Needless to say it'd be easier to just do it with javascript, but it was good practice and fun to do as well

Comment: you worked well, but I'm looking for solution in pure css,If anyone will be able to do this then that's good, :)
If no one then you answer will b acceptable :)

Comment: A pure CSS solution is close to if not impossible if you're looking to have any type of  transition between the slides on click. Is that the case?

Comment: Can you please add additional buttons with left and right arrow indicating with slider?

Comment: @Mr.beginner No. This is not a site to ask people to do work for you for free. This is a site where you come when you have questions about specific problems with your code after having attempted a solution yourself and honestly cannot complete the task. I shouldn't have even answered the original question because you didn't provide your attempts (thus making it a bad question), but it was an interesting topic to me so I did it for personal reasons

Comment: Thanks for it, but I did not asking it to do free for me, Actually my aim was not only add navigation but also side buttons like in jQuerry slider as show in the pic above, so i also want to add that too thats why i asked you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have pure CSS slider: https://github.com/drygiel/csslider

If you want to auto change images you have to use CSS animations to animate left-margin.